# IE6 and IE7 Input padding CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, forms

I have input boxes with a height of 25 pixels. In Firefox, Safari and IE8 automatically vertically align the text of it in the middle correctly.
However in IE6 and IE7 the text is aligned to the top.

How may I resolve this? Adding padding-top increased the total height of the input as I have explicitly declared its height.

I don't wish to use browser specific CSS.

Thanks.

Comment: You may be interested in this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Related issue: Chrome will do the same thing.

Solution: Decrease the `height` by `x` pixels and increase `padding-top` by `x` pixels.

eg.

```
input { 
    height: 15px; /* roughly 1.2 times font-size, or equal to line-height if set */
    padding: 5px 0; /* add padding to top and bottom to pad out the height to required height */
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The most easy fix for is to use a line-height value for example

`input[type=text]
 {
        border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
        height: 28px;
        line-height: 25px;
 }`

Answer (score 2):

```
.input{
    height:50px;
    color:#F00;
    vertical-align:middle;
    *padding-top:20px;/*IE7 and IE6*/
    *height:30px;/*IE7 and IE6*/
}
```

If the input form height is `50px` then use the above code. Note the `*` hack for IE6 and IE7.

Answer (score 0):

you can used the line-height as the height of you text box.